# (JAVA) Запись в файл

Tags: java

Пишу программу, которая заходит в папку, находит 3 текстовых документа, копирует их содержимое и в нужном порядке заливает в один новый текстовый документ. Все работает, вот только в созданном файле все в одну строчку получается. Код записи в файл:

```
for(String i: fileNames){
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dirName+"\\"+i));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dirName+"\\"+"superfile.txt",true));
String str;
while ((str=br.readLine())!=null){
bw.write(str);
}
br.close();
bw.close();
}
```

Как сделать так, что-бы записывало в файл построчно, а не вписывало все строки в одну линию?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так пишите переводы строк между строк

```
bw.write('\n');
```

или

```
bw.write("\r\n"); // для винды
```

А ещё лучше не читать построчно, а тупо байты скопировать. Но можно и так.

Comment: Вот же я балда, пытался так записать bw.write(str+"\n"); и не срабатывало, а написать отдельной строчкой не додумался.
Спасибо!

Comment: А это тоже должно было сработать, но это хуже. Просто вы наверное блокнотом проверяли, а он не понимает \\n, а только \\r\\n

Answer (score 7):

лучше пишите `bw.write(System.lineSeparator());// и для винды и для мака и для всего подходит`

Comment: Тогда уж [`bw.newLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine--).